# How to change position of calendar in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one  calendar application for that i have used TapkulLibrary.But in that calendar is display in top of the view.I want to display in bottom of view.I don't know where i have to change x and y position.can you give me idea about that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`frame`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) property of the [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) object to change both its x,y origin as well as its size.

```
myView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```